# Use of !"".equalsIgnoreCase()

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I've seen this code:

```
if (!"".equalsIgnoreCase(queue) && queue.equalsIgnoreCase("my_data"))
{
}
```

Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: Which part are you not understanding? The `!`? The `equalsIgnoreCase`? The `""`? The `&&`?

Comment: It is obvious ! is for NOT. And equalsIgnoreCase method check two Strings are equal and case doesn't matter.  But here `!"".equalsIgnoreCase(queue)` means check variable `queue` is not empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it means:

```
if (
    !"".equalsIgnoreCase(queue) //variable queue is not the empty string
    &&  // And
    queue.equalsIgnoreCase("my_data") //variable queue is equal to "my_data" without taking the case into account. This means "MY_DATA" will also be true
) {
}
```

it should probably have been written as:

```
if ("my_data".equalsIgnoreCase(queue)) {
}
```

This way it will not throw errors in case queue is `null` but will still apply the validation.

Answer (score 5):

It's just bad code that should be replaced with

```
if (queue.equalsIgnoreCase("my_data"))
```

or with

```
if ("my_data".equalsIgnoreCase(queue))
```

if `null` is a valid value for the variable `queue`.

The first operand tests that queue is not equal, ignoring the case, to the empty string. First, ignoring the case when comparing to the empty string is useless. Second, since the queue must be equal to `"my_data"` anyway to execute the `if` block, testing that it's not equal to the empty string is redundant: a queue which is equal to `"my_data"` will *always* be different from the empty string.

Comment: Or better, `"my_data".equalsIgnoreCase(queue)`

Comment: Which has the risk of an NPE. But you're right, it is bad code. It looks as if the left and the right part were written by different people.

Comment: If the queue should not be null (and generally, I prefer avoiding nulls), then it's a good thing to have an NPE: it spots a bug in the code.

Comment: I agree, you should not swap as it would change the behaviour of the code and so would not be a refactor I would recommend without seeing the rest of the code. Nasty as it might be, it could rely on the NPE.

Comment: @user902383 if `queue` is null, `!"".equalsIgnoreCase(queue)` is true, and the second check is evaluated, leading to an NPE just as my suggested replacement.

Comment: I actually prefer to get a NPE when I don't expect `null` to be a valid member of my list. Allowing comparing with it might hide serious bugs in my code..

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase(null)` returns `false` according to docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

Comment: @BackSlash no. the empty string is not equal to null. So `"".equalsIgnoreCase(queue)` is false, so `!"".equalsIgnoreCase(queue)` is true, so the second operand is evaluated, so it throws an NPE.

Answer (score 1):

`"".equalsIgnoreCase(queue)` this checks is string `queue` equals empty string
`!` is negation so `!"".equalsIgnoreCase(queue)` stands for `queue` is not empty

`queue.equalsIgnoreCase("my_data")` checks is `queue` equals "my_data" and it is ignoring case, so `My_DaTa` will satisfy this as well

`if (!"".equalsIgnoreCase(queue) && queue.equalsIgnoreCase("my_data"))` means if queue is not empty and is equal to `my_data` which actually can be refactor to

`if ( "my_data".equalsIgnoreCase(queue))`

Answer (score 1):

`!` is for NOT and equalsIgnoreCase method check two Strings are equal and case doesn't matter. But here `!"".equalsIgnoreCase(queue)` means check variable `queue` is not empty. If variable `queue` is not empty then this condition will be true.